# Free service for checking for DNS errors on your domain?

Tags: domain-name-system

Is there a free service for checking for common DNS errors on your domain?  I previously used [dnsstuff.com](http://dnsstuff.com/) for this, but they since moved to a paid model.

Comment: Didn't realize dnsstuff.com went to a paid model.  :-(

Comment: Do not regret it, they were always spending spurious warnings about missing glue...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I use a combination of:

- **IntoDNS:** http://www.intodns.com/serverfault.com

and

- **DNSsy:** http://dnssy.com/report.php?q=serverfault.com

...as well as manual querying using **dig**, **host**, **WHOIS**, etc...

Comment: IntoDNS has no IPv6 support (and therefore produces spurious errors on IPv6-only nameservers). It sends errors when there is no "www" name in the zone which is quite stupid. It can not test TLD (it says "Invalid request!)

Comment: DNSsy has no IPv6 support (and therefore produces spurious errors on IPv6-only nameservers). It sends errors when there is no "www" name in the zone which is quite stupid.

Answer (score 7):

There are several. I recommend [Zonecheck](http://www.zonecheck.fr/demo/), which is also available as free software that you can install on your own machine. The greatest thing about Zonecheck is that you can edit the configuration to change the policy (changing severity of tests from warning to fatal or the opposite, not running some tests, etc).

[DNScheck](http://dnscheck.iis.se/) is nice, too, and the only tool able to check DNSSEC.

I wrote a [paper](http://www.bortzmeyer.org/tests-dns.html) listing and comparing many online tools.

Comment: Hmmm, Zonecheck stops on first error, which isn't helpful (at least, in the web interface).

Answer (score 5):

Try this one:

http://www.squish.net/dnscheck/

Comment: As they say on the page, for experts only (it is quite low-level).

Answer (score 4):

A couple more:

- http://www.checkdns.net/
- http://www.howismydns.com/tools.php

And a [quick guide on how to check your DNS yourself](http://rscott.org/dns/).

Comment: howismydns.com has no IPv6 support and fail to detect the issue, so it produces spurious errors on IPv6-only nameservers. I

Comment: checkdns sends a spurious (and quite stupid, IMHO) warning when you have only one MX server. It seems to indicate a lack of knowledge regarding the way email works.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely check out http://dnscog.com/report/serverfault.com

They give a nice detailed report and supply some recommendations too.