# Check public DNS health and RFC compliance

Tags: domain-name-system, blacklist, rfc

Every now and again I like to run checks on my DNS servers to make sure they are running right and to RFC spec. I used to use the DNSTools website to do this as it gave me a pretty good picture of what was going on - are all my servers responding to the outside world, and the important (NS, MX especially ) records still up and replicated right. Also to see if my MX records have managed to make it onto any blacklists.

Blacklists have always been kind of a pain as I haven't been able to find a reliable "one stop shop" that lets you check against most of the major blacklists out there.

I haven't used DNS tools in a while and now they are requiring you to pay (which I have nothing against, just hard to justify to the superiors when you have invested in a large internal monitoring solution and I'm just doing a "feel good check")

What do my fellow sysadmins uses to check on their DNS records?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/7489/free-service-for-checking-for-dns-errors-on-your-domain

Comment: @l0c0b0x: My search foo must have been off i did search first. Although i'm still very interested in the Blacklist check part of my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not like the old DNSStuff but http://www.iptools.com/ and http://www.mxtoolbox.com are good replacements.

Answer (score 2):

I've found http://clez.net/net.dns to be good replacement has some other tools which are worth looking at too.

Comment: http://www.intodns.com/ might also be worth looking at.

Answer (score 2):

I use zonecheck (http://www.zonecheck.fr/). It doesn't do everything that some paid DNS checking services do, but it does do many check, is both free and Free, and is available in many distros' standard repositories (see [here](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/zonecheck) and [here](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/zonecheck-cgi) for Debian/Lenny) so is relatively easy to install on your own internal services instead of relying on other sites.

Answer (score 1):

What about [intodns.com](http://intodns.com) ? It's a really good site an provides a really good analysis of your DNS.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.squish.net/dnscheck/ is what i used even before dnstools limited their services. it's really good, reports open recursive dns and possible misconfigurations straight from root dnses down to your server.

http://robtex.com/ has also some nice dns tool - mostly for checking blacklists, although this site is mainly useful for whois and bgp ASNs lookups.

Answer (score 0):

I've used http://atrey.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~mj/sleuth/ before. You can use the online form or download the program used to do the checks.

Comment: Does not work with IPv6 name servers (it spits a spurious error, saying they don't have A records). But its biggest problem is that it reports an error when the tested server is NOT recursive! A tool to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

There is a long list of current online DNS checking services (with explanations of why some are better than others) in [my paper](http://www.bortzmeyer.org/tests-dns.html).

Executive summary: [Zonecheck](http://www.zonecheck.fr/demo) and [DNScheck](http://dnscheck.iis.se/).