# HTTP 404 Checking Service

Tags: web-server, http, http-status-code-404

I'm looking for an online service that crawls your site reliably and reports back on HTTP 404s, Page not Found errors. I don't want to install any software but just get an e-mail when a 404 is present on a couple of sites without trawling through logs.

I found this but it just deals with DNS mostly: [Domain Errors](https://serverfault.com/questions/7489/free-service-for-checking-for-dns-errors-on-your-domain)

Anyone have any recommendations please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this tips from Google Analytics Blog: http://analytics.blogspot.com/2006/09/tip-tracking-404-pages.html